# All USB devices randomly disconnecting in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, 19.04

I recently bought a new PC (i7-9800X, 3.8GHz, 1TB SSD, 16GB RAM) and installed Ubuntu 19.04 a few days ago. After a random period of time of use, could be 30 minutes or several hours, or sometimes not at all, both the wired keyboard and mouse will stop working. Plugging into a different USB port does not help, and the only solution is to perform a reboot at which point they function normally until they both dropout again. There are no other peripherals connected apart from keyboard and mouse. The mouse LED will stay on when this happens, however if I unplug and reconnect to a different USB port it will not come on at all.

This is very unlikely to be hardware problem as they work normally on reboot, and I use them regularly with an external monitor linked to a Mac laptop, where I have never had any issues.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I've checked power/usb settings, see below.

Tried disabling xhci handoff but it was not effective.

[usb config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duwSi.jpg)
[power settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYzJa.jpg)

Comment: It can be UEFI settings related. Check whether there's some power saving setting related to the USB hub.

Comment: Hi, I checked power settings but there wasn't anything that seemed relevant to USB power, I could be wrong, I've attached screenshots in original message.

Comment: "Plugging into a different USB port does not help" really does mean it is hardware related. There is something active that shuts down USB power -otherwise- reconnecting a device will trigger it to be activated. See the WARNING part: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.13/driver-api/usb/power-management.html  Linux does NOT power down USB by itself. "For this reason, by default the kernel disables autosuspend (the power/control attribute is initialized to on) for all devices other than hubs. Hubs, at least, appear to be reasonably well-behaved in this regard." as of kernel 2.6.22

Comment: (continued) The link has tons of info and settings you can check.

Comment: If plugging it into another port doesnt work, it sound like the machine is disabling the USB Bus for some reason (possibly self-protection from over-volt or current). Can you try another device in those ports when it happens to see if the whole bus is down or its just those two devices? Usually, if there was a power problem, you would get a blue/warning screen and possibly a hard reset. Did you build this machine? What is the model info of PC, keyboard and mouse?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Keyboard is a Das keyboard for Mac - DASK4MACSFT, Mouse is a logitech G502. PC settings are above, it was custom built by PC supplier. Both the mouse and keyboard will disable simultaneously, usually during simple tasks like web browsing, replugging in either will do nothing so screen is non-responsive.

Comment: Since about two weeks, I have the same problem, but it does nocht affect mouse and keyboard (so far) but only USB-drives, which reconnect shortly after disconnecting. Open shells lose their working directory (I have to do "cd $PWD") and some programs crash. I fear that the contents of the drives might get damaged.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where my USB keyboard would keep disconnecting. The eventual solution was to update my BIOS. This was with an AMD B550 motherboard and 5800x.